# Using Regex Pattern with Jsoup on a Weblink

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I'm trying to make a parser to get products info on a Website. I've made a similar tool with Php and Regex, and I wish to do the same with Java. The objective is to get a parent link, to make child products links with regex for getting their products info in a loop

```
String curl = TextField1.getText();
URL url = new URL(curl);
URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
String strLine = "";

while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("style='color:#000000;font-weight:bold;'>(.*?)</a>");       
    strLine = strLine.replaceAll(" ","_");
    strLine = strLine.replaceAll("d'","d");

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(strLine);
    while(m.find()){
        String enfurl = "http://www.exemple.com/fr/"+m.group(1)+".htm";
        System.out.println(enfurl);
    }
}
```

This code works, but someone tell me that Jsoup is a better solution to parse html. I'm reading the Jsoup documentation, but after establish a connexion, I don't know which syntax I must choose. Could you help me ?

EDIT : Ok, with this code :

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href][title*=Cliquer pour obtenir des détails]");
for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
    String urlenf = link.attr("href");

    Document docenf = Jsoup.connect(urlenf).get();
    System.out.println(docenf.body().text());
}
```

I've got the links... but now, I must open another Jsoup connexion to get product info, and this test don't works. How Could I use another Jsoup in the for loop ? thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Does it show an error? Please explain what's the problem

Comment: It's seems that's a UTF-8 problem, because there is "é" in the url. So my var urlenf contains url like : "www.exemple.com/pédalier", and the loop stop whith that. But if I put in urlenf : "www.exemple.com/p%C3%A9dalier", the loop works. How could I correct that ?

Comment: Did any of the answers below helped at all?

Comment: No, and I don't understand why. Because when I paste the url in my browser to test it's works, but Jsoup can't connect on this url. I have no error in the console, so, is there an exception for getting more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the urls (and generally, the content) like this.

```
String url = "PAGE_URL_GOES_HERE";
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
String encoding = "UTF-8";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(is , encoding , url);
```

**Update**

Are you sure the problem is with the encoding of the url?
I tried the below code, and it works just fine.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String url = "http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/écrémer/27576?q=écrémé";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                .userAgent("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)")
                                .get();

            System.out.println(doc.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

In any case, try this one too, `Jsoup.connect(new String(url.getBytes("UTF-8")))`

Comment: You're right, it's not only an encoding problem. Exception log helps me to correct Jsoup syntax error.

Comment: Glad I could help. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples of jsoup usage on the net.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(targerUrl).get(); //get html page

Elements descElements = document
            .select("table#searchResult td:nth-child(2) font.detDesc"); // find elemets by css selectors

for (int i = 0; i < descElements.size(); i++) {
        String torrentDesc = descElements.get(i).html(); //get tag content
}
```